# Javascript async/await on promise return pending, how to get the value instanly?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I build chrome extension with javascript. here is my code :

```
async function getlocalstorage() {
    var theresult = '';
    await new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action:'getlocalstorage',data:"version"}, function(response){
            if (response.data!=='null') {
                theresult = resolve(response.data);
            } else {
                theresult = reject(response.data);
            }
        });
    })
    return theresult;
}

window.onload = function (){
    console.log('this should be the first output');
    /*it's returning pending status*/
    console.log(getlocalstorage());
    console.log('this should be the last output');
}
```

but the return of console.log(getlocalstorage()); is pending status . . . how to do that ?

Comment: Did you mean: await

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the value instantly because `getlocalstorage` is asynchronous, but you can write to the console in the order in which you are expecting. Make the `onload` function `async` and await the value of `getlocalstorage()`:

```
window.onload = async function (){
    console.log('this should be the first output');
    console.log(await getlocalstorage());
    console.log('this should be the last output');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What `console.log(getlocalstorage());` print is a promise.Your getlocalstorage function actually return a promise and has ignored the return statement. You need to wait for it to resolve.
You need to add the **await** keyword before the function call: `console.log(await getlocalstorage());`

By the way, you can await on a promise directly. Here is an example of getting the current active tab using async/await.

```
let getActiveTabAsync = () => {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
      let { lastError } = chrome.runtime
      if (typeof lastError !== 'undefined') reject(lastError);
      else resolve(tabs[0]);
    });
  });
}
let activeTab = await getActiveTabAsync()
console.log(`The current active tab id is ${activeTab.id}`)
```